# Bash - forced fixed variable length, can I do it easier than this?

Tags: bash, variables

I need to convert variable so it has exact length, if it's too short then extend it for spaces, it it's too long then cut it. E.g. for variable of 11 characters

```
$ var1=a
$ echo ${#var1}
1
$ var1=$(echo $var1 | sed 's/$/           /' | cut -c 1-11)
$ echo ${#var1}
11
```

While above works, it does not seem to be very handy for cases where I need long strings so I am looking for something more appropriate and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `printf`:

```
formatted=$(printf "%11.11s" "$var1")
```

**Examples:**

```
printf "%11.11s\n" "a"
          a

printf "%11.11s\n" "abcdefghijklmnop"
abcdefghijk
```

You can see it is making output exact 11 char long.

Comment: It seems to be working apart from the fact that is gives me the trailing comma, but it works when I leave the comma out:  $(printf "%11.11s" "$var1"), thanks for quick help!

Comment: Ah comma was my mistake (coding habits from c, awk etc). Check my updated answer.

Comment: There is one more problem, I need those spaces to be added as trailing, not to beginning, so the result above should be rather: "a            ", not "         a". Can it be done?

Comment: Yes you can use: `printf "%-11.11s\n" "$var1"`